# Tests that are working locally are skipped in travis-ci

Tags: ios, swift, travis-ci

I am trying in vain to integrate one of my projects with travis CI. Locally, everything is fine.

I have the following in my .travis.yml:

```
language: objective-c
before_install:
  - brew update
  - brew upgrade xctool
osx_image: xcode7.2
xcode_workspace: PsychoApp.xcworkspace
xcode_scheme: PsychoApp
xcode_sdk: iphonesimulator9.2
```

The build seems to pass without any issues, but the tests are skipped (both ui and unit tests).

I get the following message (only unit tests to stay short):

```
run-test PsychoAppTests.xctest (iphonesimulator9.2, iPhone 4s, application-test)
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
skipping: No test cases to run or all test cases were skipped.
```

After that, the build is marked as successful.

Details about the project:

- Created with XCode 7.2 using default single view application template
- Swift language
- Uses Cocoapods for several dependencies, hence the use of workspaces
- Only one scheme, Psychoapp, created by default with the correct targets set for testing
- Using default test target created by xcode at the start of the project
- Tests are running locally

Did anyone experience similar issues?

Best regards

============

EDIT: 
As Greg Combs mentioned, I was able to make my tests be executed by fixing issues regarding some of my swift files not being visible to my test targets (both UI and unit tests).

As a bonus, here is a travis script that has not given me any issues:

```
language: objective-c
osx_image: xcode7.2
script:
 xctool -workspace PsychoApp.xcworkspace -scheme PsychoApp test -sdk    iphonesimulator9.2 -destination platform='iOS Simulator,OS=9.2,name=iPhone 6s'
```

Comment: Is the scheme marked as shared?

Answer (score 1):

At least in my case, this was caused by xctool hiding the fact that some of the tests didn't successfully execute due to runtime errors.  Looking deeper into the logs, I had to fix some issues in my dependency frameworks.

Comment: Not sure if it was XCTool's fault in my case, but I indeed encountered several issues linked to my frameworks (and their visibility with regards to test targets)... Anyway, I will edit my original post with a working .travis.yml.